# How do you delete half-downloaded/cancelled Windows Store Apps?

Tags: windows-10, storage, windows-store

I was downloading something from the Windows Store, and it froze:

[image: >>Screenshot of the problem<<]

If you cancel the process it is still kept in storage and does not delete it which takes a massive amount of storage from my 250GB SSD.

Tried going into settings to reveal the hidden folders but the Windows Apps folder shows 0kb which is very strange.

I can't finish downloading it even when I have a lot more storage that it needs left.

How can I delete it to free up my storage, or continue the download?

My Windows 10 OS is up to date and so are all the Windows 10 apps.